# Explain code for scrollable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is used to implement a scrollable HTML table.
Can someone explain how this jQuery code works?

What does `$("table > *").width()` mean and how does the `scrollLeft()` affect the function when the table is scrolled either left or right?

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
    $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function() {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 25px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
}
thead {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}
tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 140px;
}
td,
th {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/X2Kmd/1/)

Comment: What exactly you want to know?

Comment: @Gabriel this part of the function  $("table > *").width() and how does the scrollLeft affect the function, when the table is scrolled either left or right,

Comment: It does nothing at all... just scrolling with mouse, with jQuery code doing nothing...

Comment: It's simple and genius :D
if you remove the jQuery line , when you scroll right you will see that the Y-scroll is stuck next to the Column 3 because the table width=300px and each TD min-width = 100px , and the tbody LEFT POSITION is changed -1 , -2 , -3 , etc..  , so logically the Scroll of the Y-scroll of tbody will follow tbody position 
So if we add the value that we scrolled to the width of the Tbody , the scroll will maintain a POSITION of 0 because ,

the more the scroll value is , the same is the value that we are adding to the width of tbody


Hope you understood me

Comment: @Diptox got your explanation thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollLeft()` there increases width of tbody, so that its vertical scrollbar is always attached to right side of the table at any scroll position.

That table is declared as display:block so it is not a table actually. Neither `tbody` and `thead` there are table-row-group elements - they are blocks.

Under the hood CSS layout engine wraps rows there into anonymous table-row-group that do not have scrollbars.

Comment: how does one get the same scroll effect without using the display:block

Comment: display:table elements are special in the sense that they do not overflow as if min-width:min-content are defined on them. So you will not be able to see scrollbars on them.

Answer (score 2):

Just read.

Table on scroll set width to thead & tbody by table width + table scroll left offset. scrollLeft scrollLeft will add offset and increase width for tbody & thead to push rows and colls and follow scroll position. Do not delete this jquery code. This will help you.

Comment: That code has nothing with responsive design. Consider to remove or rephrase your answer.